# FOSUserBundle - Symfony2 - Login/Registration issues

Tags: authentication, registration, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I'm using FOSUserBundle to manage users in my application.
But finding a problem after login, and after registration.

After registration, a confirmation email is sent successfully, but the redirect page at          `myapp.com/register/check-email` generates the following error:

`Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a NULL variable ("") in FOSUserBundle :: layout.html.twig at line 9`

If I click on the link in the email sent to me it seems that the user is successfully activated even if the url myapp.com/register/confirmed returns:

```
This user does not have access to this section.
```

If I try to log in, instead of the profiler Symfony signals that are not authenticated in the system.

Comment: please paste some code

Comment: Please check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376701/impossible-to-access-an-attribute-username-on-a-null-variable