# Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a NULL variable ("")

Tags: symfony

Trying to display the username of the logged in user by putting

```
{{ app.user.username }}
```

in base.html.twig gives me an error like

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a NULL variable ("") in ::base.html.twig at line 45
```

Acessing it like

```
{{ app.security.getToken().getUser().getUsername() }}
```

results in the following error.

```
Impossible to invoke a method ("getUser") on a NULL variable ("")
```

How to acess the logged-in user's attributes globally in symfony? How to fix the error?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try to check first if user exists, and then get its username:

```
{% if app.user %}
    {{ app.user.username }} 
{% endif %}
```

or do it with ternary operator:

```
{{ app.user ? app.user.username }}
```

You could use [default](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html) Twig filter to set default value if username is empty:

```
 {{ app.user.username|default('undefined') }}
```

Comment: yes..the problem is my 'app.user' is null.But my user is logged in as admin.How to figure out the issue?

Comment: Got it! The problem was the page i was refreshing to see the result was not behind the firewall.Thanks for your help.